# what is meant "Express the following as polynomials in α of degree at most 2"?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

I've been studying Ring and field theory online recently and I came upon a confusing question today.

Let α be a root of the polynomial $X^3 + 4X + 2$ over $Q$. What is the degree of $Q(α)/Q$?
Express the following as polynomials in α of degree at most 2.

(a) $α^4$

(b) $(α + 1)^3$

(c) $(α + 1)^{-1}$

I understand the first part. the degree of the extension is obviously 3 but I don't know what is meant by "in alpha" isn't this just a root ? secondly what do they mean by expressing alphas as a polynomial ? maybe it's just lack of sleep and this is more obvious than it seems right now but any help would be appreciated. I think if i could even see one example I'd be able to get a handle on it .

Comment: For example, you may find $a, b, c\in \mathbb{Q}$ s.t. $\alpha^{4} =a\alpha^{2}+b\alpha+c$. This is what it means.

Comment: ah okay I think i understand. so for this one we know $α$ is a root so we can say $α^3+4+2=0$ which gives after some manipulating gives $α^2={-2}/{α}-4$so $α^4={4}/{α^2}+{16}/{α}+16$. is it something like that you mean ?

Comment: That's the quadratic polynomial in $1/\alpha$, not $\alpha$. For each (a), (b) and (c), you have to find appropriate polynomial $f(x), g(x), h(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree at most 2 such that $\alpha^{4} =f(\alpha), (\alpha+1)^{3}=g(\alpha), (\alpha+1)^{-1} = h(\alpha)$. Not in $1/\alpha$.

Comment: that's kinda my question, I'm not sure how to that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a), you can find polynomials $q(x), r(x)$ s.t. $x^{4} = (x^{3}+4x+2)p(x)+r(x)$ with $\deg r\leq 2$. If we put $x=\alpha$, we get $\alpha^{4}=r(\alpha)$, so $r(x)$ is the desired polynomial. You can do the same way for (b).

For (c), you can find $x^{3}+4x+2 = (x+1)s(x)+c$ for some $s(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $c\in \mathbb{Q}$, then for $x=\alpha$, $0=(\alpha+1)q(\alpha)+c$.

Comment: thanks :) i was just wondering though is there a way to find out what r(x) is or is it enough to just say $\alpha^{4}=r(\alpha) $?

Comment: You have to find such $r(x)$, and to find it, just divide $x^{4}$ into $x^{4}+4x+2$.